# Testimonial slider with center testimonial bigger and copy reveal

Tags: html, jquery, slider

Good day,

I'm trying to built a jQuery slider (with no plugins) Testimonials as per the image below:

Testimonial slider example:
[image]

The red box will be the visible part for the user.

The animation should work as follow:

Person 2 will be in view as page loads, after 3 seconds person 2 needs to move to the left and person 3 needs to move to the center - as it moves to the center it needs to reveal copy.
Person 1 will move to the next in line (looping function)

This is my current jQuery:

```
    setInterval( function () {

    $(".people-carousel-container .inner-testimonial").append(
        $('.people-carousel-container .slide')
            .first().removeClass("active").addClass('small'));
        $(".people-carousel-container .slide")
            .first().removeClass('small').addClass("active")
}, 4000);
```

This is my current HTML:

```
                        <div class="inner-testimonial">
                        <div class="slide small">
                            <h4>Great platform Easy to use and received my first product today!</h4>
                            <div class="image-box">
                                <img src="resources/front/img/profile-placeholder-img.png" alt="product image">
                                <p>Jane Smith</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide active">
                            <h4>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation quis minim</h4>
                            <div class="image-box">
                                <img src="resources/front/img/profile-placeholder-img-1.png" alt="product image">
                                <p>Jonny Tell</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="slide small">
                            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli. dolor</h4>
                            <div class="image-box">
                                <img src="resources/front/img/profile-placeholder-img-2.png" alt="product image">
                                <p>Mick Dooper</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Is there away to built this?